# Moving beetween jsps page stored in WEB-INF

Tags: jsp, web-inf

Hi I doing web aplication using mostly jsp with jstl with login for clients and admins For security (to avoid access page with typing url) i moved some jsp page to webinf folder I know how to access jsp page in web-inf folder from outside But the problems is that i cant do it between jsp pages stored in web-inf Any idea how i can do it? I was thinking to keep one page outside this folder wchich will be redrirecting using dispatcher and url will be created by values passed in urls from pages inside web-inf (i got menu and every href will be sending some different values) But i dont know how to create url using path plus value from url

Comment: You can't; that's the point: clients cannot directlt access pages under WEB-INF.

Comment: So is there any way to pass some values in url (from href) to jsp outside web-inf and there create url based on this values? This way i think should help to avoid create many jsp pages for using dispatcher

Comment: You use a controller (i.e. servlet) as the url that the client sees and the servlet can access the jsps that are in web-inf by forwarding to them. (Forward not redirect) See the info page associated with the servlets tag.

Comment: i got problems to make this controller servlet I cant find any good tutorial (im using NetBeans)